# Java method doesn't print out anything after running

Tags: java, methods

I'm making a little card game in java. Right now, I'm working on hand classifications. However, when I run the method 'handclassifier', I don't get anything. Here's an example of what eclispe outputs into the console:

## Standard Output

```
Your hand: 6 of Spades, Queen of Spades
Creek: 10 of Spades, 9 of Spades, Queen of Clubs 
Current value:
```

As you can see, the handclassifier method doesn't return anything at all, even when the requirement for a pair is met. I have it run after the first 2 methods so that the cards can load up and be classified by the method. Is there something wrong in the code for the comparisons?

## Main Code Section

```
package Deck;
import java.util.*;
public class creek {
    public static int i, ii;
    public static boolean stop = false;
    public static String card1, card2, fcard1, fcard2, fcard3, cv1, cv2, cs1, cs2, fv1, fv2, fv3,        fs1, fs2, fs3;
    public static String[] rank = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    public static String[] suit = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};

    public static void hand() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int counter = 0;

        for(counter = 0; counter < 1; counter++) {
            i = ran.nextInt(12);
            ii = ran.nextInt(3);
            cv1 = rank[i];
            cs1 = suit[ii];
            card1 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii] ;
        }
        for(counter = 1; counter < 2; counter++) {
            i = ran.nextInt(12);
            ii = ran.nextInt(3);
            cv2 = rank[i];
            cs2 = suit[ii];
            card2 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
        }
        if (card1.equals(card2)) {
            while(card1.equals(card2)) {
                i = ran.nextInt(12);
                ii = ran.nextInt(3);
                card2 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
                cv2 = rank[i];
                cs2 = suit[ii];
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
        System.out.printf("Your hand: %s, %s",card1,card2);
    }
    public static void flop() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int counter = 0;

        for(counter = 0; counter < 1; counter++) {
            i = ran.nextInt(12);
            ii = ran.nextInt(3);
            fcard1 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
            fv1 = rank[i];
            fs1 = suit[ii];
        }
        for(counter = 1; counter < 2; counter++) {
            i = ran.nextInt(12);
            ii = ran.nextInt(3);
            fcard2 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
            fv2 = rank[i];
            fs2 = suit[ii];
        }
        for(counter = 2; counter < 3; counter++) {
            i = ran.nextInt(12);
            ii = ran.nextInt(3);
            fcard3 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
            fv3 = rank[i];
            fs3 = suit[ii];
        }
        if (fcard1 .equals(card1) || fcard1.equals(card2) || fcard1.equals(fcard2) || fcard1.equals(fcard3)) {
            while(fcard1.equals(card1) || fcard1.equals(card2) || fcard1.equals(fcard2) || fcard1.equals(fcard3)) {
                i = ran.nextInt(12);
                ii = ran.nextInt(3);
                fcard1 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
                fv1 = rank[i];
                fs1 = suit[ii];
            }
        }
        if (fcard2.equals(card1) || fcard2.equals(card2) || fcard2.equals(fcard1) || fcard2.equals(fcard3)) {
            while(fcard2.equals(card1) || fcard2.equals(card2) || fcard2.equals(fcard1) || fcard2.equals(fcard3)) {
                i = ran.nextInt(12);
                ii = ran.nextInt(3);
                fcard2 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
                fv2 = rank[i];
                fs2 = suit[ii];
            }
        }
        if (fcard3.equals(card1) || fcard3.equals(card2) || fcard3.equals(fcard1) || fcard3.equals(fcard2)) {
            while(fcard3.equals(card1) || fcard3.equals(card2) || fcard3.equals(fcard1) || fcard3.equals(fcard2)) {
                i = ran.nextInt(12);
                ii = ran.nextInt(3);
                fcard3 = rank[i] + " of " + suit[ii];
                fv3 = rank[i];
                fs3 = suit[ii];
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("\nCreek: %s, %s, %s \n", fcard1, fcard2, fcard3);
    }
    public static void handclassifier() {
        while(stop = false) {
            if(cv1.equals(cv2) || cv1.equals(fv2) || cv1.equals(fv2) || cv1.equals(fv3) || cv2.equals(fv1) || cv2.equals(fv2) || cv2.equals(fv3) || fv1.equals(fv2)|| fv1.equals(fv3) || fv2.equals(fv3)) {
                if(cv1.equals(cv2) && cv1.equals(fv1) || cv1.equals(cv2) && cv1.equals(fv2) || cv1.equals(cv2) && cv1.equals(fv3) || cv1.equals(fv1) && cv1.equals(fv2) || cv1.equals(fv2) && cv1.equals(fv3) || cv2.equals(fv1) && fv1.equals(fv2) || cv2.equals(fv2) && fv2.equals(fv3) || fv1.equals(fv2) && fv2.equals(fv3)) {
                    if(cv1.equals(cv2) && cv2.equals(fv1) && fv1.equals(fv2) || cv1.equals(cv2) && cv2.equals(fv1) && fv1.equals(fv3) || cv1.equals(cv2) && cv2.equals(fv2) && fv2.equals(fv3) || cv1.equals(fv1) && fv1.equals(fv2) && fv2.equals(fv3) || cv2.equals(fv1) && cv2.equals(fv2) && cv2.equals(fv3)) {
                        System.out.println("Four of a Kind");
                        stop = true;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Three of a Kind");
                    stop = true;
                }
                System.out.println("Pair");
                stop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hand();
        flop();
        System.out.println("Current value: ");
        handclassifier();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while(stop = false) {
```

should be

```
while(!stop) {
```

or

```
while(stop == false) {
```

You are assigning `false` to the `stop` variable instead of comparing its current value to `false`.